# How do I maintain several sql queries on different databases in same transaction using spring JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have my entities and repositories setup for 2 databases

`persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="user_per_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.User</class>
    <class>com.example.Order</class>
    <class>com.example.Package</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="stock_per_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.example.Stock</class>
    <class>com.example.Graph</class>
    <class>com.example.Change</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.user.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="userEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="userTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="userEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName"    value="user_per_unit" />
    <property name="dataSource"             ref="userDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"       ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="userEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${size}" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="${maxtotal}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${maxidle}" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="${minidle}" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.stock.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="stockEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="stockTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="stockEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName"    value="stock_per_unit" />
    <property name="dataSource"             ref="stockDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"       ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="stockTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="stockEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="stockDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${size}" />
    <property name="maxTotal" value="${maxtotal}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${maxidle}" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="${minidle}" />
</bean>
```

Now in my class I am doing several `CURD` operations in a method like

`userRepository.updateUser(...);`

`userRepository.addUser(...);`

`userRepository.deleteUser(...);`

`stockRepository.updateUser(...);`

`stockRepository.addUser(...);`

`stockRepository.deleteUser(...);`

How can I start a transaction at the top and if something fails in the process, revert back to original state before I started my method.

Comment: Are your JDBC drivers XA compliant? If so you'll need to enable a JTA transaction manager instead of a simple one. Once you do that you'll need to expect slower transactions too.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have no idea if JDBC drivers are XA compliant

Comment: You'll need to check with the provider. If they are not XA compliant there's no way you would be able to have a **single** transaction that encompasses two databases. Essentially you need to enable a two-phase commit.

Comment: @TheImpaler I have access to mysql admin, is there a way I can check if its compliant ?

Comment: An "informal" way that I have used is to get the JDBC driver version string using `Connection.getDatabaseMetaData()` and then looking it up in the MySQL web site. However, I would formally ask the operations team to make sure this will work in production when the time comes.

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you. I check with my team and my JDBC drivers are XA compliant, how can I use JTA to get all of them in one transaction ?

Comment: JDBC drivers for MySQL are available in the Connector/J package. The basic MySQL JDBC driver class is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in version 5.x and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` in version 8.x. This driver **is not XA-compliant**. For XA support, Connector/J provides `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` in version 5.x and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource` in version 8.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ChainesTransactionManager to get this working

`applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="chainedTxManager" class="org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="userTransactionManager"/>
            <ref bean="stockTransactionManager"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and used annotation over my class as

`@Transactional(value = "chainedTxManager")`

When ever any query on any db fails, I am throwing an exception and its automatically rollingback, if no exception, its committing.